# How to go frame by frame on mouse click in tkinter (Python3.x)?

Tags: python, video, tkinter, onclick, frame

I have code from a few sources on stack overflow that I have put together. It plays a video and records click positions in the window. I would like it to go frame by frame and advance after each click. I am unsure how to begin.

```
video_name = input_file()
video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)

def stream(label):
    for image in video.iter_data():
        image_frame = Image.fromarray(image)
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_frame)
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def leftClick(event):
        x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
        y = root.winfo_pointery()- root.winfo_rooty()
        print(x, y)
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_label = tk.Label(root)
    my_label.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)
    my_label.bind("<Button-3>", rightClick)
    my_label.pack()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(my_label,))
    thread.daemon = 1
    thread.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for any suggestions you might have for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `video.get_data(...)` to load frame instead of using `for` loop.  Also you do not need to use `thread` to read frame from video, use click event handler.  Below is an modified version of your code as an example:

```
frame_index = 0 # current displayed frame index in the video file

def stream(label, offset=0):
    global frame_index
    try:
        # read a frame image from video file
        image = video.get_data(frame_index+offset)
        # convert the image to tkinter supported format
        image_frame = Image.fromarray(image)
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_frame)
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image
        # update frame_index if image is loaded successfully
        frame_index += offset
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error loading frame:', ex)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_name = input_file()
    video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_label = tk.Label(root)
    my_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: stream(my_label, +1))
    my_label.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e: stream(my_label, -1))
    my_label.pack()
    stream(my_label) # load first frame
    root.mainloop()
    video.close() # close the reader
```

Note that **mouse left click** is used to show next image in the video, **mouse right click** is used to show previous image in the file.